# Email applications for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, email

Recommend a user-friendly email application for Ubuntu.

Comment: You should go to the Software Recommandations SE. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

But anyway, i use Thunderbird, it's a bit clumsy but gets the job done.

Comment: Any code for terminal through which i can directly download thunderbird ?

Comment: See here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux

Comment: You should to ask more concrete question. It is not clear what do you mean: a transport server (MTA), a client (MUA) or a delivery server (MDA)

Comment: [Ubuntu terminal email client](http://askubuntu.com/questions/499330/ubuntu-terminal-mail-client) and [Email application for the computer-impaired](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2829/email-application-for-the-computer-impaired) are not primarily opinion-based, but this question which is about GUI email applications too apparently will not pass the same test.

Comment: @shcherbak I see no reason why the requirements for this question have to be different from the requirements for the other two questions about software recommendations for email clients that I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz There are two other questions about software recommendations for email clients on Ask Ubuntu that I linked to in a previous comment. There is also a  [`software-recomendation`](http://askubuntu.com/tags/software-recommendation/info) tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never liked Evolution when it was the default email application in Ubuntu. It was buggy, but I put up with it anyway. Every time I updated Evolution I checked if the bugs had been fixed, but they never were. I switched to Thunderbird when it became the default email application in Ubuntu, and I stuck with Thunderbird because I never had a single bug with it and Thunderbird is very easy to use.

For software recommendations for terminal email clients see [Ubuntu terminal email client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499330/ubuntu-terminal-mail-client). For software recommendations for email applications for people with special accessibility requirements see [Email application for the computer-impaired](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2829/email-application-for-the-computer-impaired).